# How to decrement ( - - ) all the elements of an array at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays

So i have this array that has ten elements each with the value of ten:

> int health1[] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};

How is it possible to decrement (- -) all the elements in the array at the same time?

```
health1--;
```

Call above gives: Type mismatch, "int[]" does not match with "int"

Comment: Is it okay to iterate through each value in the loop?

Comment: Just because the answer is "you can't" doesn't make this an unreasonable question. Here, have an upvote :-)

Comment: Thanks lol ;D Sure got a lot of down-voting for asking this :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to decrement every value in a single operation.

I would iterate over the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < health1.length; i++) {
  health1[i]--;
}
```

About the error you are getting: This is because `health1` is an array of integers, but `--` is an operator for an integer itself. Because of this, it doesn't make sense to the compiler to subtract `1` from a container, as a container is not numerical. Thus the "types" are "mismatched".

Comment: Doing it in a single *line* is easy. Just keep your fingers away from the Enter key. ;-)

Comment: This is now possible with Java 8 streams, please see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible. You must use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < health1.length(); ++i) --health1[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `for(;;)` header allows for any kind of expression in the third position (where `i++` usually goes), you can write a `for` loop with an empty body:

```
for (int i = 0; i != health1.length; health1[i++]--);
```

Despite the "cool" look of this one-liner, its readability is rather poor, compared to a regular `for` loop.

Comment: And executionally no faster than the conventional for.

Answer (score 1):

Of course **you cannot**.

Explanation is simple: you are running code in the main single thread, which means that your code will transform in a stack of instructions that will run in order how they are, so you have just one solution to iterate this array and decrement each element by element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < health1.length; i++) health1[i]--;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know ahead of time that all of the elements of the array are the same, you can use `Arrays.fill` to create a new array of the same length and get the required value from the first element.

```
Arrays.fill(health1, health1[0] - 1);
```

Otherwise, you have to loop.

Comment: But if all of the elements were the same, it'd be silly to have an array in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 streams introduced `.map()`.

```
int numbers[] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};

int[] result = Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x -> --x).toArray();
/* result contains [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]. */
```

To get it even more *"at the same time"* you could add `.parallel()` between `.stream()` and `.map()`, but this will cost performance for setting up and would not recommend unless the list was huge.

Answer (score 0):

For loop principles: initialisation, condition, interration

I knows the length of the health1
I is >= 0. (It will loop until reaches that point)
Since it knows the length it will decrement from the end.

```
for(int i = health1.length; i >= 0; i--){
 System.out.println(health[i])  
}
```